# C++ Number guessing game with feedback

Tags: c++, arrays, random

for a class I have been asked to create a random number guessing game that generates a random 5 digit number then prompts the user to guess the number.  The game then generates feedback to help the user make a better guess (assuming they didn't guess right the first time).  For example if the first number in both the random number array and the user guess array match the game outputs a 1, if the first number in the guess array does not match the first number in the random number array but matches one of the other numbers, the game outputs a 2; if the first number in the guess array does not match any numbers in the random number array, the game outputs a 0 (i. e. if random number array = 31350 and user guesses 32010, the feedback would print as 10221).  I think I have it mostly done but the feedback portion is not working properly.  The output is a 20+ digit number and regardless of the input, it says the correct number was guessed.  Here is my code so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
bool checkGuess(int numberToGuess[], int guess[], int size);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int DIGITS = 5;
    int numberToGuess[DIGITS]; //declares array holding the random string of numbers
    int guess[DIGITS]; //declares array holding the user guesses

    srand(time(NULL));  //random seed

    cout << "Welcome to the number guessing game!\n";
    cout << "In this game you will try to guess a random 5 digit number" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)  //loop to generate the random number
    {
        numberToGuess[i] = rand() % 9 + 1;
    }

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter your guess: " << endl;  //prompts user for their guess
        cin >> guess[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        bool comparedGuess = checkGuess(numberToGuess, guess, 5);
        if (comparedGuess == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)
            {
                if (guess[i] == numberToGuess[i])
                {
                    guess[i] = 1;
                }
                else if (guess[i] == numberToGuess[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
                {
                    guess[i] = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    guess[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)
        {
            cout << guess[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
    while (guess[DIGITS] != numberToGuess[DIGITS]);


    cout << "You guessed it correctly!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool checkGuess(int numberToGuess[], int guess[], int size)  //function to compare user guess to random number
{
    if (guess[size] == numberToGuess[size])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: `numberToGuess[i] = rand() % 9 + 1;` can never generate 0. Try `numberToGuess[i] = rand() % 10;`

Comment: Good catch, I have changed it but the feedback system is still not working properly.

Comment: `cin >> guess[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` does not work quite the way you want it to. The compiler should be telling you that. Ditto `guess[i] == numberToGuess[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @user4581301 the compiler did not give me any errors regarding that although I thought that might be my issue, do you have a suggestion on how I can fix that?

Comment: Default warning level may be too low. Not sure how to turn that up in visual studio. Easiest fix is to read into a std::string instead of the char array and then test that the string is exactly 5 characters.

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately the directions for this project require use of arrays

Comment: Lousy way to teach. "Here kid, I want you to learn how to do it wrong...." Also Just noticed that `int guess[DIGITS];` the input is expecting you to type in numbers which is sort of what you want, but would read in the whole number in one shot, not digit by digit. Input 12345 would give 12345 in guess[0] and nothing in guess[1]. I'll explain this better below where there is room.

Comment: *" is not working properly"* is not a very motivating problem description.

Comment: @ChristianHackl By not working properly I mean it outputs a 20+ digit number then proceeds to say the number is entered correctly

Comment: Edit your question to pop that in. Basic format for a good question goes along the lines of: "I want to do this. For input X I expect output Y and instead get output Z. Here is my code: blob of code."

Comment: @user4581301 In response to your earlier comment, is there a way for me to prompt the user to input a 5 digit number and have each digit stored in consecutive spots in an array?

Comment: This is non-trivial, unfortunately.Probably the easiest way to do this without string is `cin.getline(bigTempArrayOfChar, sizeof(bigTempArrayOfChar));` If you do not get five digits, reapeat and discard until the line ends and start over.

Answer (score 0):

OP's output was bad because input is wrong. Their may still be problems in the output, but garbage in, garbage out. Let's fix the input first.

Pro tip: Divide a program up into it's pieces and make sure each piece works before moving on to pieces that depend on them. In this case there are four parts:

1. Getting a random number
2. Getting a guess from the user
3. Matching the random number with the guess
4. Output the match results is almost a gimmie if the matching is well done

Getting a random number was covered in the question comments.

Getting user input can be done a number of ways. The best is with a string. The Instructor has disallowed strings. This teaches students to write brittle code or vastly overcomplicate what should be an introductory assignment. Bad form, teach.

My answer to that is smurf them. Provide non-brittle program with cantankerous user input. Any deviation from the specified input format invokes the FOAD (BLEEP Off And Die) protocol, ending the program.

```
cout << "Please enter your guess: " << endl;  //prompts user for their guess
char temp[8];
temp[5] = 'C'; // canary value
cin.getline(temp, sizeof(temp));
if (temp[5] != '\0')
{ // if the did not enter exactly five characters
    cout << "Bad input. You LOSE!";
    return 0;
}
for (int index = 0; index < DIGITS; index++)
{ // ensure all input characters are digits
    if(isdigit(temp[index]))
    {
        guess[index] = temp[index] - '0'; //convert from char to int and store in guess
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Bad input. You LOSE!";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Matching the random number with a guess

I'm not going to write this one out completely because this is, or should be, the point of the assignment. The OP's logic is more-or less right, but the syntax is wrong.

What is required is

A loop through all guessed digits. check.

A test to see if the current guessed digit matches the randomly selected digit.

And here's where it goes wrong. You can't do this`if (guess[i] == numberToGuess[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])` to check the elements of an array. You need another loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS; j++)
{ // test current user input against all
    if(i!=j)
    { // skip the i==j case because it's already been checked
        if (guess[i] == numberToGuess[j])
        {
            guess[i]= 2;
            break; // stop looking
        }
    }
}
```

One last piece is needed: the exit condition. How do you know if you are done? The OP's cut won't work.

```
bool checkGuess(int numberToGuess[], int guess[], int size)  //function to compare user guess to random number
{
    if (guess[size] == numberToGuess[size]) <-- BOOM!
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

`guess[size] == numberToGuess[size]` will compare one element of guess against one element of numberToGuess, not the whole array. Worse, it compares outside the bounds of the arrays because array indexes are only valid from 0 to size-1.

This would require another loop, but that loop is already being performed in step one of the array matching. No point repeating it. OP can either test guess for all 1s (which requires a loop, so why bother?) or keep a count of how many matched digits were found. Exit on count == 5.

At this point output is taken care of because all it says is whether or not a match was found. To get to the output a match must have been found or the matcher still needs work.